# how do i/can i access a sessionid cookie through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies

I've installed the cookie extension for jquery, and am attempting to access the session id cookie.

I currently have two cookies for my session - see screenshot below:

[image: cookie screen shot]

however, $.cookie() only lists one:

```
> $.cookie()
Object {csrftoken: "fFrlipYaeUmWkkzLrQLwepyACzTfDXHE"}
> $.cookie('sessionid')
undefined
```

can i/how do i access the sessionid cookie from javascript?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to, as the session id cookie should be set to HTTP Only, preventing access from javascript. And indeed, the screenshot shows that it is.

Comment: is the explanation for this documented somewhere?

Comment: It's a security issue, so the session id isn't exposed by an xss vulnerability.

Comment: mind popping your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The session id cookie should be marked as HTTP Only, preventing access from javascript. This is a security issue, preventing session hijacking via an xss vulnerability.

You can see in your screenshot that the cookie is indeed marked as HTTP.

---

If you want to learn more about the flag see [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly). Originally implemented by IE, most browsers support the flag nowadays, and session cookies not marked http-only are considered a security flaw. Also see [here](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/session-cookie-httponly-flag-java/).